# Data from 4 different database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to get data from 3 different databases on one event command. Can anybody tell me any efficient way besides I am querying to all three different database servers in a row:-
Server 1 : Select * from ....
Server 2 : Select * from.....
and so on...

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you querying data from separate databases in the the one physical server, or from separate databases in different servers?  And does the data in  each query have the same or different columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as the question is marked TSQL:

1. Install the providers for the 'other' databases.
2. In SQL Server 2005, [create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to each database, and then simply query as though the 'other' databases were SQL Server databases.

Answer (score 1):

If the databases are on the same server instance, they can be queried in the format "database_name.table_name.column_name" otherwise I would use Mitch's answer (linked servers can be queried in the format "server_name.database_name.table_name.column_name")